# Java proposals not showing for dependencies

Tags: java, maven

General Java question here / a little maven-y also. I downloaded the parent pom from a repository and did a mvn install to get all of the dependencies, but now when I am writing code, specifically in the example below, I might write something like: `conn.` and expect the proposals to show up, but they are not. Now say I were to a go step further (since I have it in front of me) and say `conn.tableOperations().` I would expect theses [proposals](https://accumulo.apache.org/1.6/apidocs/org/apache/accumulo/core/client/admin/TableOperations.html) to show up, but like I said they are not. Here is a pic of what I am talking about if that explanation didnt suffice:

[image]

If I were to type `String bla;` then `bla.` all of the proposals would show up for that? I know it must / is related to the dependencies but I have never had this problem before. I did a bit of digging and found that maybe a `maven clean install` with the proper parameters would help, but I have zero clue what they would be. This is what I am referring to in this regard.

[image]

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Alright I solved my problem. I couldn't see the proposals because the project I was trying to edit was still inside of the parent project, which wasn't considered a Java project, hence why the Java proposals weren't showing up. I drilled down into the parent project to the project I was trying to edit, right clicked and clicked "Import as project". It keeps the project still under the parent project and edits are made to both, but now the inner project is considered a Java project. Everything works as expected now.

Comment: not sure why I am downvoted? If this is the solution to the problem I was having it was the solution? Grief much

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused about Maven and Eclipse interaction.

> I downloaded the parent pom from a repository and did a mvn install to
>   get all of the dependencies...

That is your first mistake. `mvn install` is not what you think it is.

1. You need to start by installing [Maven integration in Eclipse](http://eclipse.org/m2e/).
   This is either already available depending on which package solution
   you chose, or it is available in the Eclipse marketplace.
2. Next you need to create a new Maven project in Eclipse.
3. Lastly you need to specify a dependency on the jar in the m2e
   plugin. This will automatically bring in all the necessary
   dependencies into your project workspace.

Note the above link has full documentation, including a [Getting Started](http://eclipse.org/m2e/documentation/m2e-extension-development.html) tutorial.

Comment: I am not confused. As you can see, the line `final ZooKeeperInstace zoo = ...` is working fine. ZooKeeperInstance is from a dependency and so is Connector. The dependencies are there, the JavaDoc is not.